# Importing multiple CSV files to google sheets with Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a google script to import CSV files from web urls to individual sheets in a google sheet.  I would like to have it clear the contents of certain columns before importing the new info.  I had had trouble getting the script to clear contents prior to importing.  I have also had in include part of one CSV along with another on a sheet.  I think I need to add something to the script between CSV files.  I also need something added to clear contents prior to importing.  I don't want to just clear the sheet because there are formulas that need to remain.  I also don't want to use the Google IMPORTDATA function because it is unreliable.

Here is my current script (URLs removed):

```
function importCSVFromWeb() {

  var csvUrl = "http://csvurlhere";
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('spreadsheeturlhere');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var ss = sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

  var csvUrl = "http://csvurlhere";
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('RentPaid');
  var ss = sheet.getRange(3, 3, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

  var csvUrl = "http://csvurlhere";
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Tenants');
  var ss = sheet.getRange(1, 2, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

  var csvUrl = "http://csvurlhere";
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Owners');
  var ss = sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear the contents of a sheet or a range of cells within a sheet, you can use [`sheet.clearContents()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clearContents()) or [`range.clearContent()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearContent()), which will remove only values & leave your formatting & formulas in tact.

I note that your line `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('spreadsheeturlhere');` does nothing as you subsequently redeclare the `ss` variable.  If the script is bound to a spreadsheet, you don't need this line as calls to `getActive()` & `getActiveSheet()` will give you a reference to the host spreadsheet. Your calls to `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName()` are returning references to the host spreadsheet anyway, not the one you open by URL.

I would also consider changing your function to accept the CSV source URLs, sheet names & cell anchors as parameters so that the code is easier to maintain.  e.g.

```
function importCSVFromWeb(csvUrl, sheetName, dataAnchor) {
  /* csvUrl:     the CSV source URL
     sheetName:  the name of the sheet to add the data
     dataAnchor: the cell origin for the range.setValues() call as an array 
                 i.e. dataAnchor = [row, col]
  */
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // note that you'll need to pass in a name for each sheet, 
  //   including the first one where you used SpreadsheetApp().getActiveSheet() previously
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange(dataAnchor[0], dataAnchor[1], csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}

function feedCSVImport(){
  var urls_sheets_list = [["csv_source_url_1", "Sheet1", [1,1]],
                          ["csv_source_url_2", "RentPaid", [3,3]],
                          ["csv_source_url_3", "Tenants", [1,2]],
                          ["csv_source_url_4", "Owners", [1,1]]
                         ];
  for(var i = 0, lim = url_sheets_list.length; i < lim; ++i){
    importCSVFromWeb(url_sheets_list[i][0], url_sheets_list[i][1], url_sheets_list[i][2]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am implementing these changes and am getting the following error:

"TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. (line 23, file "Code")"

Line 23 is:
    importCSVFromWeb(url_sheets_list.length[i][0], url_sheets_list.length[i][1], url_sheets_list.length[i][2]);

Comment: Sorry, @Rob.  I've fixed the typos in the example.  It's not pretty, but it was intended to demonstrate a way of breaking down your problem.

Comment: This is working great, thanks for the help @Dean Ransevycz.  If I wanted to incorporate the range.clearContent(), how do I add that to the parameters so it clears the range before entering the new content?

Comment: If you want to clear data from all of the sheets, then you don't need to add a new parameter.  I'd only consider adding a boolean parameter if you want to flag specific sheets to be cleared before pasting the data --
 you could call the `clearContent()` method based on that. Have a look at the `sheet` class (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) as well, specifically the `getLastRow()` & `getLastColumn()` methods.  Have a go at solving the problem & ask another question if you get stuck.