# How to read a file in server with google-apps-script?

Tags: google-apps-script, server

I need to recover a .csv file located on a local server that contains information about the silos, and which will regenerate regularly.
I then copy the information in a google sheet so that I can process it in my application. I use google-apps-script.

I have already done a script to retrieve information from the CSV file that works but only from a file store in the google drive.

The problem is that I would like to recover my file directly from a server (which I know the ip address, and the destination path.) Instead of recovering it in a drive.

I look for google script functions to do that a good part of the after, but I found nothing conclusive. I'm asking you if you ever had to do that.

Is there a google-apps-script function to do what I want?

Have a good evening.
Cordially.

Comment: Look in utilities.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing multiple CSV files to google sheets with Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46880914/importing-multiple-csv-files-to-google-sheets-with-google-script)